# How would I conduct a sociological study on hair bias?

Tags: sociology

For my intro to sociology class, I’d like to do a mock study about how strongly people associate specific categories of common hairstyles with economic status and racial identity. My problem is I’m not sure what the most practical, efficient method of probing people for their opinions on hairstyles would be.

Logically I can’t directly ask whether “do you think person with (dreadlocks, bold-cut, etc.) is poor?”, I’m thinking about doing something in the context of “if you were an employer and (person with select hairstyle) came in for a job interview, what would your first impression be of their values/work ethic?”

Is my research question too broad in scope? I’m struggling to formulate how to go about gathering data for people’s implicit biases with hair.

Comment: You could start looking at established methodology of [implicit association tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit-association_test). There is, no particular effective method for (unconscious) bias mitigation that I'm aware of, so it's unclear what you might do with the results.